# зачем условной переменной нужен мьютекс

Tags: c++, многопоточность, c++11, mutex, condition-variable

1. зачем блокировать мьютекс с помощью `unique_lock` перед тем как вызывать метод `wait` у условной переменной?
2. зачем в качестве параметра методу `wait` нужен мьютекс, ведь если бы я хотел я бы и сам блокировал нужный мьютекс, после пробуждения?
3. нужно ли блокировать тот же самый мьютекс перед вызовом `notify_one` для условной переменной в другом потоке?

немного контекста

```
#include <iostream>

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

std::mutex outputStreamMutex;

std::mutex productMutex;
std::condition_variable condVar;
bool productReady = false;

class Product 
{
public:
  void make() {}
} product;


void makeProduct()
{
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(outputStreamMutex);
    std::cout << "making process...\n";
  }

  {
    std::lock_guard lock(productMutex);
    product.make();
    productReady = true;
    condVar.notify_one();

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockStream(outputStreamMutex);
    std::cout << "product is made\n";
  }
}

void send(const Product& prod)
{
  //...
}

void sendProduct()
{
  {
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(outputStreamMutex);
    std::cout << "waiting product process...\n";
  }

  {
    std::unique_lock lock(productMutex);
    condVar.wait(lock, []() {return productReady;});
    send(product);
    productReady = false;

    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockStream(outputStreamMutex);
    std::cout << "product is sent\n";
  }
}


int main()
{
  std::thread makerThread(makeProduct);
  std::thread senderThread(sendProduct);
  makerThread.join();
  senderThread.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: а можно немного контекста к вопросам?

Comment: Читайте документацию прежде чем задавать вопросы.

Comment: @user7860670 прочитал, довольно скромно написано делай так и все или я просто не пойму, хотелось бы прочитать как опытные люди своими словами могут объяснить это, если вопрос настолько плох могу удалить

Comment: @Ildar, вы [man pthread_cond_wait](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_wait) и [man  pthread_cond_signal](https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_cond_signal) прочли? Imho там все понятно описано. Вкратце, такие действия нужны для атомарного (без гонок) захвата потоками мьютекса

Comment: По поводу вопроса 3) -- *`"The pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal() functions may be called by a thread whether or not it currently owns the mutex that threads calling pthread_cond_wait() or pthread_cond_timedwait() have associated with the condition variable during their waits; however, if predictable scheduling behavior is required, then that mutex shall be locked by the thread calling pthread_cond_broadcast() or pthread_cond_signal()."`*. Формально можно вызывать, не владея мьютексом,  но для предсказуемого поведения потоков, лучше владеть им, вызывая notify

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Типовое использование условной переменной без плюсового сахара обычно выглядит как-то так (псевдокод)¹:

```
condition_variable cv; // условная переменная
mutex dataMutex;       // Мьютекс, контролирующий доступ к данным
MyData data;           // Некоторые пользовательские данные

Consumer() {
  dataMutex.lock();        // Захват мьютекса, дабы данные не изменялись во 
                           // время проверки предиката
  while(!data.isReady()) { // Проверка, не готовы ли данные
    cv.wait(dataMutex);    // Ожидание сигнала от производителя, когда он изменит 
  }                        // данные

  // ... какая-то обработка данных ...

  dataMutex.unlock();      // Освобождение мьютекса т.к. он более не используется
}

Produser() {
  while (1) {
    dataMutex.lock();        // Захват мьютекса, чтобы изменить данные
    data.doWork();           // Какая-то обработка данных
    cv.notify_one();         // Пробуждение одного потока, ждущего в очереди
    dataMutex.unlock();      // Освобождение мьютекса, дабы потребитель смог
  }                          // проверить своё условие и обработать данные
}
```

Типовая реализация условной переменной в самом примитивном случаеустроена как-то так(также псевдокод):

```
struct condition_variable {
  mutex cvMut;                     // Внутренний мьютекс защищающий доступ к очереди.
  queue<thread_t*> waitingQueue;   // Очередь потоков, ожидающих сигнала
  
  void wait(mutex dataMutex) {
    // Добавление текущего потока в очередь ожидания
    cvMut.lock();
    waitingQueue.push(this_thread);
    cvMut.unlock();
    
    dataMutex.unlock(); // Освобождение мьютекса доступа к данным,
                        // дабы производитель мог с ними работать
    suspend();          // Приостановка работы и ожидание сигнала о пробуждении

    dataMutex.lock();   // Захват Мьютекса обратно, дабы внешняя программа смогла
                        // проверить, выполнено ли условие.
  }

  void notify_one(){
    // Получить процесс из очереди ожидания
    cvMut.lock();
    thread_t *thread = waitingQueue.pop();
    cvMut.unlock();
     
    // Если очередь не пуста, то разбудить ожидающий поток.
    if(thread) {
      restart(thread);
    }
  }
}
```

Реализация `suspend()` и `resume()` системно-зависимы. Например, в классических UNIX-системах они могут строится на сигналах с помощью [`sigsuspend()`](http://ru.manpages.org/sigsuspend/2)/[`kill()`](http://ru.manpages.org/kill/2), а в современном (2.4+) GNU/Linux они строятся на [`futex`](http://ru.manpages.org/futex/2)'ах.

---

> 1. зачем блокировать мьютекс с помощью `unique_lock` перед тем как вызывать метод `wait` у условной переменной?

Как видно из типовой реализации выше, блокировка должно удерживаться от проверки условия и до добавления потока в очередь ожидания. Если бы её не было, то из-за состояния гонки была бы возможна такая последовательность событий:

```
Потребитель   : проверяет условие.
Производитель : изменяет данные
Производитель : проверяет, что очередь ожидания пуста и ничего не делает
Потребитель   : добавляет себя в очередь
Потребитель   : засыпает и ждёт сигнала
```

В итоге потребитель может остаться спать неопределённо долго, хотя условие уже выполнено. Блокировка собственно не даёт Производителю менять данные между проверкой и добавлением себя в очередь.

Использование именно `unique_lock`, а не `std::lock_guard` обусловлено тем, что последний не может быть разблокирован. Можно было бы обойтись и обычным `std::mutex::lock()`/`unlock()`, но в С++ это чревато висящей блокировкой, если кто-то бросит исключение (см. общую мотивацию к использованию объектов-блокировок).

> 2. зачем в качестве параметра методу `wait` нужен мьютекс, ведь если бы я хотел я бы и сам блокировал нужный мьютекс, после пробуждения?

см. типовую реализацию и ответ на (1). Важно блокировать его во время проверки условия и до добавления потока в очередь ожидания включительно.

> 3. нужно ли блокировать тот же самый мьютекс перед вызовом `notify_one` для условной переменной в другом потоке?

В данном случае не обязательно, но его надо захватывать при любом изменении данных, которое может вызвать изменение выполнения условия. к моменту посылки сигнала о пробуждении его уже можно отпустить.

Если на условной переменной ожидает не более одного процесса, то абсолютно никакой разницы нет. Но, как [предупреждает POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_broadcast.html), если необходимо «предсказуемое поведение планировщика» при наличии нескольких потребителей, то его следует одерживать т.к. в таком случае возможна ситуация голодания в том числе и более приоритетного потока.  см. [подробности здесь](https://austin-group-l.opengroup.narkive.com/lKcmfoRI/predictable-scheduling-behavior-in-pthread-cond-broadcast).

---

<sup>¹ Здесь и далее барьеры памяти не указаны</sup>

Comment: спасибо! вот еще классный материал по условной переменной https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/c-core-guidelines-be-aware-of-the-traps-of-condition-variables, вдруг кому пригодится