# реализовать семафор без мьютекса

Tags: c++, многопоточность, семафоры, atomic

есть наивная реализация семафора...

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>

#include <cstdint>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

extern int errno;

struct semaphore_exception : public std::exception
{
    semaphore_exception(const char* msg) noexcept {}
};


//! Simple semaphore realization with std::mutex and std::condional_variable
class simple_semaphore
{
public:
    simple_semaphore(std::uint32_t scount, std::uint32_t timeout_msec)
    : m_limit(scount)
    , m_waiters(0u)
    {
        if (m_limit == 0u)
            throw semaphore_exception("Semaphore count must be greather than 0");

        m_timeout_msec = std::chrono::milliseconds(timeout_msec);
    }

    void wait(int id)
    {

        std::unique_lock< decltype(m_mutex) > lk(m_mutex);
        if (!m_cond.wait_for(lk, m_timeout_msec, [=](){ return m_waiters.load() < m_limit; }))
        {
            std::cout << "Timeout in milliseconds: " << std::chrono::duration_cast< std::chrono::milliseconds >(m_timeout_msec).count() << " was occured\n";
            return;
        }

        m_waiters++;
    }

    void post(int id)
    {
        std::unique_lock< decltype(m_mutex) > lk(m_mutex);
        if (m_waiters == 0u)
            return;

        m_waiters--;
        m_cond.notify_one();
    }

private:
    const std::uint32_t m_limit;
    std::atomic< std::uint32_t > m_waiters;
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cond;
    std::chrono::milliseconds m_timeout_msec;
};


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //4 simultaneous worker threads, 1 - waited
    simple_semaphore sem{4, 4000};
    auto locker = [&sem](int id){
        sem.wait(id);
        std::cout << "sleep id: " << id << "\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3u));
        sem.post(id);
    };
    std::thread thrd1(locker, 1), thrd2(locker, 2), thrd3(locker, 3), thrd4(locker, 4), thrd5(locker, 5);
    thrd1.join(); thrd2.join(); thrd3.join(); thrd4.join(); thrd5.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Вроде работает. Но есть два вопроса:

1. есть ли грубые ошибки в реализации?
2. можно ли реализовать семафору без мьютекса, чисто только на атомарном счетчике и condition variable? Или даже без condition variable?
   Изучал вопрос какое-то время, но код с использованием чистой магии атомарных операций слишком сложен и квалификации недостаточно, чтобы понять(особенно когда что-то про когерентность кэшей и мультипроцессорность). Можно ли как-то "на пальцах", для тех кто в танке, так сказать?

Comment: есть исследование (вроде Декйстры и Хоара), где доказывается, что любой примитив синхронизации можно выразить через другой, поэтому, обычно самый базовый примитив реализуется на уровне железа. Если железо или ОС не предоставляют такого "базового примитива", то сделать самому его НЕЛЬЗЯ. Поэтому, Вы можете через атомарные переменные сделать мютекс, а дальше у Вас уже все есть:)

Answer (score 5):

> есть ли грубые ошибки в реализации?

Прям грубых ошибок на беглый взгляд я не вижу, но реализация странная, что её сложно назвать «[семафором](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))»:

- Во-первых, он перевёрнут: `wait()` должен уменьшать значение счётчика, а `post()` — увеличивать.
- При создании семафора задаётся его начальное значение, а не «лимит»; и `post()` может увеличивать это значение больше изначального.

А также более мелкие замечания:

- `timeout_msec`, скорей всего, следует передаваться в качестве опционально параметра в `wait()` (или аналогичную функцию). Задавать его при создании семафора — крайне странно.
- если `wait()` может завершиться ошибкой, то у вызывающего должна быть возможность проверить это.
- Параметры `post()` и `wait()` не используются (обычно они задают, на сколько нужно увеличить/уменьшить значение семафора).
- Если значение семафора подходящее, то при использовании атомарных переменных его можно изменить без захвата блокировки (надо делать аккуратно, с применением CAS-операций, см. `std::atomic<T>::compare_exchange_weak`/`_strong` ).

> можно ли реализовать семафору без мьютекса, чисто только на атомарном счетчике и condition variable?

Без мьютекса условная переменная [не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1166689/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BC%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81/1166773#1166773).

> Или даже без condition variable?

В стандартном c++17 условная переменная — единственный способ остановить поток и дождаться наступления события в другой нитке, так что в качестве альтернативы только:

- использовать активное ожидание на процессоре
- воспользоваться средствами ОС (по сути реализовать примитив аналогичный условной переменной)

Answer (score 3):

В c++20 можно ожидать на атомарной переменной - `std::atomic<T>::wait`. Ожидание на атомарной переменной не требует захвата мьютекса, поэтому требует меньшего количества операций, в результате такой способ реализации своих примитивов синхронизации будет эффективнее, чем используя условную переменную.

В c++20 есть стандартные `counting_semaphore` и `binary_semaphore`. Реализации могут использовать `std::atomic<T>::wait`, или примитив, лежащий в его основе, или, если ОС предоставляет эффективный готовый семафор, то примитив ОС.

Comment: `std::atomic<T>::wait` — это спин-лок, т.е. это приведёт к активному ожиданию на процессоре... и стандартные реализации семафоров не могут его использовать...

Comment: @Far-Zer, `std::atomic::wait` использует пассивное ожтдание, futex, `WaitOnAddress`, или что там система предоставляет

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в  MSVC точно сделан так, знаю ибо сам делал) https://github.com/microsoft/STL/pull/1057

Comment: да... тут я был не прав — не  вчитался в описание...